# AWS .Net Core Serverless Web API - Calling another Web API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a Serverless Web API in AWS and I need to make a GET request to another third-party Web API which returns stream. But whatever I do reading from that stream does not work i.e. Lambda function just shuts down. I could not find anyone else who had the same issue. I suspect I might missing something. Any thoughts?

**Edit**: When I debug locally all works as it should.

**Edit2**: I found the issue. Yes, it is AWS specifc. I was trying to process some stuff in parallel and when the main call was finished the rest was not finished but rather shut down.

Comment: Please add some code. What do you mean by it just shuts down? Does it produce any exceptions? If so please show examples.

Comment: I will need to prepare the code since the structure is quit big. No error messages in the log. It just finishes.

Comment: Then something should be wrong with the code, like a missing operator or something. In worst case some swallowed native exception

Comment: But it perfectly works in debug. It must be something AWS specific.

Comment: If there are async calls make sure you are waiting for them to complete before the lambda handler method call finishes. If your async calls do not complete before the handler method finishes the lambda would terminate and will not wait for the async calls to complete.

Comment: Is there a way to return the response to the caller while doing something else in parallel?